# Finding the first row that meets conditions of a mask and selecting one row after it

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [100, 1123, 123, 100, 1, 0, 1],
        'b': [1000, 11123, 1123, 0, 55, 0, 1],
        'c': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    }
)
```

And this is the output that I want. I want to create column `x`:

```
     a      b  c    x
0   100   1000  a  NaN
1  1123  11123  b  NaN
2   123   1123  c  NaN
3   100      0  d  NaN
4     1     55  e  e
5     0      0  f  NaN
6     1      1  g  NaN
```

By using a mask:

```
mask = (
    (df.a > df.b)
)
```

First of all I need to find the first occurrence of this mask which in my example is row number `3`. Then I want to move one row below it and use the value in column `c` to create column `x`.

So in my example, the first occurrence of `mask` is row 3. One row after it is row 4. That is why `e` is selected for column `x`.

Note that in row 4 which is one row after the `mask`, no condition is needed. For example for row 4, It is NOT necessary that `df.a > df.b`.

This is what I have tried:

```
df.loc[mask.cumsum().eq(1) & mask, 'x'] = df.c.shift(-1)
```

I provide some additional `df`s for convenience to test whether the code works in other examples. For instance what if there are no cases that meet the conditions of `mask`. In that case I just want a column of `NaN` for `x`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1000, 11230, 12300, 10000, 1000, 10000, 100000], 'b': [1000, 11123, 1123, 0, 55, 0, 1], 'c': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']})
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1], 'b': [1000, 11123, 1123, 0, 55, 0, 1], 'c': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']})
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 100000], 'b': [1000, 11123, 1123, 0, 55, 0, 1], 'c': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']})
```

Comment: Use ```shift()``` combine with ```loc```. First, define ```mask = (df.a > df.b)``` then do ```df.loc[mask.cumsum().eq(1), 'x'] = df.loc[mask.cumsum().eq(1), 'c'].shift(-1)```.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate a mask that indicates one location past where the first value of `a` is greater than `b`:

```py
mask = (df.a > df.b).shift(fill_value=False)
mask = mask & ~mask.cumsum().shift().astype(bool)
```

You can then use that mask to set the value of `x` equal to `c`:

```py
df.loc[mask, 'x'] = df['c']
```

Output for each of your dfs:

```
      a      b  c    x
0   100   1000  a  NaN
1  1123  11123  b  NaN
2   123   1123  c  NaN
3   100      0  d  NaN
4     1     55  e    e
5     0      0  f  NaN
6     1      1  g  NaN

        a      b  c    x
0    1000   1000  a  NaN
1   11230  11123  b  NaN
2   12300   1123  c    c
3   10000      0  d  NaN
4    1000     55  e  NaN
5   10000      0  f  NaN
6  100000      1  g  NaN

   a      b  c    x
0  1   1000  a  NaN
1  1  11123  b  NaN
2  1   1123  c  NaN
3 -1      0  d  NaN
4 -1     55  e  NaN
5 -1      0  f  NaN
6 -1      1  g  NaN

        a      b  c    x
0      -1   1000  a  NaN
1      -1  11123  b  NaN
2      -1   1123  c  NaN
3      -1      0  d  NaN
4      -1     55  e  NaN
5      -1      0  f  NaN
6  100000      1  g  NaN
```

More generically, you can use `cummax` and shift by `N` to select the next `N` values:

```
N = 3
mask = (df.a > df.b).shift(fill_value=False).cummax()
mask = mask & ~mask.cumsum().shift(N, fill_value=0).astype(bool)
```

Comment: Thanks @Nick. Can you tell me if for example I want to select 3 rows after the masked row, what I should change. I know that I must figure these things by myself but I like to ask it from the PROs :) Does this approach that you use work in that case?

Comment: You can use `mask = (df.a > df.b).cummax().cumsum().between(2, 2+3)`

Comment: I'll add this as answer for the record and details (but please keep the accepted answer)

Comment: @x_Amir_x what mozway said will work. Or you could adapt mine as `mask = (df.a > df.b).shift(fill_value=False).cummax(); mask = mask & ~mask.cumsum().shift(3).astype(bool)`

Comment: @x_Amir_x it's preferable to ask all the questions at once...

Comment: @Nick My bad :)

Comment: @x_Amir_x no problems

Comment: @x_Amir_x I've added the generic code to my answer as well, although it's more slightly more complex than mozways.

Answer (score 4):

Your approach is quite close, but you need to handle the case where there are no occurrences of the mask condition. You can modify your code to check if there is at least one occurrence before attempting to set the 'x' column. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [100, 1123, 123, 100, 1, 0, 1],
    'b': [1000, 11123, 1123, 0, 55, 0, 1],
    'c': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
})

mask = (df['a'] > df['b'])

# Check if there is at least one occurrence of the mask
if mask.any():
    # Find the first occurrence of the mask
    first_occurrence = mask.idxmax()

    # Check if there is at least one row below the first occurrence
    if first_occurrence < len(df) - 1:
        # Set the 'x' column using the value in column 'c' one row below the first occurrence
        df.loc[first_occurrence + 1, 'x'] = df.loc[first_occurrence, 'c']

print(df)
```

This code first checks if there is at least one occurrence of the mask. If true, it finds the index of the first occurrence and then checks if there is at least one row below it. If true, it sets the 'x' column using the value in column 'c' one row below the first occurrence. If there are no occurrences of the mask or if the first occurrence is the last row, 'x' will be filled with NaN for the entire column.

Answer (score 4):

A generic approach could be to [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html)+[`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) then select the desired position(s):

```
N = 3
mask = ((df.a > df.b)
        .cummax().cumsum()
        .between(2, N+1)
        )

df.loc[mask, 'x'] = df.loc[mask, 'c']
```

Output:

```
      a      b  c    x
0   100   1000  a  NaN
1  1123  11123  b  NaN
2   123   1123  c  NaN
3   100      0  d  NaN
4     1     55  e    e
5     0      0  f    f
6     1      1  g    g
```

Intermediates:

```
      a      b  c    x  cumsum   mask
0   100   1000  a  NaN       0  False
1  1123  11123  b  NaN       0  False
2   123   1123  c  NaN       0  False
3   100      0  d  NaN       1  False
4     1     55  e    e       2   True
5     0      0  f    f       3   True
6     1      1  g    g       4   True
```

Comment: Took me a little while to figure this one out but it's nice...

Comment: @Nick really? I thought it was straightforward. Do you think I should add more details?

Comment: I was trying to figure it out in my head. Much easier seeing the intermediates as you have them in your answer. No need to edit.