# Finding the first row that meets conditions of a mask and selecting one row after it that meets a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is an extension to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77651219/finding-the-first-row-that-meets-conditions-of-a-mask-and-selecting-one-row-afte).

My dataframe is:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [100, 1123, 123, 100, 1, 0, 1],
        'b': [1000, 11123, 1123, 0, 55, 0, 1],
        'c': [100, 1123, 123, 999, 11, 50, 1],
        'd': [100, 1123, 123, 190, 1, 105, 1],
        'e': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    }
)
```

And this is the output that I want. I need to create column `x`:

```
      a      b     c     d  e   x
0   100   1000   100   100  a   NaN
1  1123  11123  1123  1123  b   NaN
2   123   1123   123   123  c   NaN
3   100      0   999   190  d   NaN
4     1     55    11     1  e   NaN
5     0      0    50   105  f   f
6     1      1     1     1  g   NaN
```

My mask is:

```
mask = (df.a > df.b)
```

And these are the steps needed:

a) Find the first row that meets conditions of the mask.

b) Get the value of column `a` of the above step.

c) Find the first row that the above value is between columns `c` and `d`. Being equal to one of them is also OK.

d) Get the value in column `e` and create column `x`.

For example for the above dataframe:

a) First row of mask is row `3`.

b) The value of column `a` is 100.

c) From rows that are after the mask (4, 5, ...) the first row that 100 is between columns `c` and `d` is row 5. So 'f' is selected for column `x`.

d) So 'f' is chosen for column `x`.

This image clarifies the above steps:

[image]

This is what I have tried:

```
mask = (df.a > df.b)
val = df.loc[mask.cumsum().eq(1) & mask, 'a']
```

I prefer the solution to be generic in any possible way.Like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77651477/10200497) IF POSSIBLE.

I have provided some additional dataframes in case you need to test the code with other subtle different conditions. For instance what if there no rows that meets conditions of the mask. In that case column `x` is all `NaN`s. Column names are all the same as the above `df`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [100, 1123, 123, -1, 1, 0, 1], 'b': [1000, 11123, 1123, 0, 55, 0, 1],'c': [100, 1123, 123, 999, 11, 50, 1], 'd': [100, 1123, 123, 190, 1, 105, 1], 'e': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']})
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [100, 1123, 123, 100, 1, 0, 1], 'b': [1000, 11123, 1123, 0, 55, 0, 1], 'c': [100, 1123, 123, 999, 11, -1, 1], 'd': [100, 1123, 123, 190, 1, 10, 1], 'e': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']})
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [100, 1123, 123, 1, 1, 0, 100], 'b': [1000, 11123, 1123, 0, 55, 0, 1], 'c': [100, 1123, 123, 999, 11, -1, 50], 'd': [100, 1123, 123, 190, 1, 10, 101], 'e': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']})
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [100, 1123, 123, 100, 1, 1000, 1],'b': [1000, 11123, 1123, 0, 55, 0, 1],'c': [100, 1123, 123, 999, 11, 50, 500], 'd': [100, 1123, 123, 190, 1, 105, 2000], 'e': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']})
```

Comment: maybe first create code for every step and later try to make it `"generic"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
import numpy as np

target = df.loc[(df.a > df.b).cummax().cumsum().eq(1), 'a']
df['x'] = target
df['x'] = df['x'].ffill()
cond = df['x'].between(df['c'], df['d']) & df['x'].notna()
df['x'] = np.where(cond.cummax().cumsum().eq(1), df['e'], float('nan'))
```

df

target value is 100 & The first row's c is 100 and d is 100.(it means c & d equal target value 100)

Judging from the fact that the value of the e column of the first row was not made into the value of the x column,I found a matching condition below the 4th row (index: 3), which is the target.

---

chk with your test code

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [100, 1123, 123, -1, 1, 0, 1], 'b': [1000, 11123, 1123, 0, 55, 0, 1],'c': [100, 1123, 123, 999, 11, 50, 1], 'd': [100, 1123, 123, 190, 1, 105, 1], 'e': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']})
```

apply code and return:

[image]

Comment: can you describe you solution in answer?  It could be useful for other users. BTW: In my code I created list with all cases so you may use it to test your code on other cases. Some of them gives empty `mask` and I had to use `if` or `try/except` - I wonder how it will work with your solution.

Comment: @furas variable `target` is a series. If there is no value that matches the condition, it becomes an empty series.

`df['x'] = target`: This code works even if variable `target` is an empty series, so make all NaN column.

The next step will be understood without any major problems.

Comment: could you describe it in answer, not in comments - so it would be useful for other people which will read your answer.

Comment: @furas I think describe is useful, but it is not mandatory. and not always.  In my English, describe can even cause unnecessary misunderstandings, so I don't do it when I can't explain well in English.  it is possible that  to not explain my answers in English can be more useful.

Answer (score 1):

I would create code for every step and eventually later I would try to create it more `generic`.

And first I would create column `x` with default value `NaN`

```
df['x'] = np.NaN
```

Next I would use your `mask` with `iloc[0]` to get first matching row. And it I could get its `name` as `index` (because it is `Series`) and value `['a']`
for next step

```
mask = (df.a > df.b)

first = df.loc[mask].iloc[0]
index = first.name
val   = first['a']
```

Next I would use this to create mask to search next row

```
mask = (df.index > index) & (val >= df['c']) & (val <= df['d'])

row = df[mask].iloc[0]

print('row  :')
print(row)
```

And I would use index from this row to put `e` in `x` in original `df`

```
df.loc[row.name, 'x'] = row['e']
```

---

I didn't test it on other cases.

I have no idea how to short it to something `generic`.

---

Full working code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [100, 1123, 123, 100, 1, 0, 1],
        'b': [1000, 11123, 1123, 0, 55, 0, 1],
        'c': [100, 1123, 123, 999, 11, 50, 1],
        'd': [100, 1123, 123, 190, 1, 105, 1],
        'e': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    }
)

df['x'] = np.NaN

print(df)

mask = (df.a > df.b)

first = df.loc[mask].iloc[0]
index = first.name
val   = first['a']  
print('index:', index)
print('val  :', val)

mask = (df.index > index) & (val >= df['c']) & (val <= df['d'])

row = df[mask].iloc[0]
print('row  :')
print(row)

df.loc[row.name, 'x'] = row['e']
print(df)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Code which test all cases.

Some of them gives empty mask so I have to add `if` to check it (or `try/except` to catch error)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

all_dfs = [
    pd.DataFrame({'a': [100, 1123, 123, 100, 1, 0, 1],
                  'b': [1000, 11123, 1123, 0, 55, 0, 1],
                  'c': [100, 1123, 123, 999, 11, 50, 1],
                  'd': [100, 1123, 123, 190, 1, 105, 1],
                  'e': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']}),
    pd.DataFrame({'a': [100, 1123, 123, -1, 1, 0, 1], 
                  'b': [1000, 11123, 1123, 0, 55, 0, 1], 
                  'c': [100, 1123, 123, 999, 11, 50, 1], 
                  'd': [100, 1123, 123, 190, 1, 105, 1], 
                  'e': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']}),
    pd.DataFrame({'a': [100, 1123, 123, 100, 1, 0, 1], 
                  'b': [1000, 11123, 1123, 0, 55, 0, 1], 
                  'c': [100, 1123, 123, 999, 11, -1, 1], 
                  'd': [100, 1123, 123, 190, 1, 10, 1], 
                  'e': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']}),
    pd.DataFrame({'a': [100, 1123, 123, 1, 1, 0, 100], 
                  'b': [1000, 11123, 1123, 0, 55, 0, 1], 
                  'c': [100, 1123, 123, 999, 11, -1, 50], 
                  'd': [100, 1123, 123, 190, 1, 10, 101], 
                  'e': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']}),
    pd.DataFrame({'a': [100, 1123, 123, 100, 1, 1000, 1],
                  'b': [1000, 11123, 1123, 0, 55, 0, 1],
                  'c': [100, 1123, 123, 999, 11, 50, 500], 
                  'd': [100, 1123, 123, 190, 1, 105, 2000], 
                  'e': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']})
]

for df in all_dfs:
    print('---------------')
    
    try:
        print('--- before ---')

        df['x'] = np.NaN

        print(df)

        print('---')

        mask = (df.a > df.b)

        if not mask.any():
            print("Can't find any matching row !!!")
            continue

        first = df.loc[mask].iloc[0]
        index = first.name
        val   = first['a']  
        print('index:', index)
        print('val  :', val)

        print('---')

        mask = (df.index > index) & (val >= df['c']) & (val <= df['d'])
        
        if not mask.any():
            print("Can't find any matching row !!!")
            continue
            
        row = df[mask].iloc[0]
        print('row  :')
        print(row)

        print('--- after ---')

        df.loc[row.name, 'x'] = row['e']
        print(df)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
```